# Sharing Google Analytics between a Drupal and a Wordpress installation

Tags: wordpress, drupal, google-analytics

Given the needs of a client, he uses wordpress as a publishing platform; The news section of the website
and drupal as the community/classifieds section of his website.

Each CMS is on its own folder/directory. `example.com/wp` and `example.com/drup`

I'm wondering if there was an effective way of sharing the same Google Analytics account/ID.
Any best practices ? Suggestions ?

Answer (score 5):

Just include the same GA code with the same ID and it'll all go into the same account. Nothing fancy necessary if it's all on the same domain name.

Answer (score 1):

As ceejayoz mentioned, throw in the same GA code and it will work fine. However, I'd suggest taking it a step further and use filters to segment the traffic into different profiles. Typically I'd set it up as so:

- A master profile with all the data, unfiltered
- A profile for just the wordpress install
- A profile for just the drupal install

This allows more play with your data, without extra coding.